# Application Data c# win mobile 8 not working as described

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, storage, application-data

I'm trying to set up local settings so I can store data in my Windows Mobile 8 app. The first step I'm trying is:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Just having that in my code causes the app to fail when debugging on my device.

Any ideas why?

I have `"using Windows.Storage;"` set. The actual code doesn't throw up any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the `IsolatedStorageSettings` feature, as below:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            if (!settings.Contains("test"))
            {
                settings.Add("test", urlText.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                settings["test"] = urlText.Text;
            }
            settings.Save();
```